# Why compiling two c file at a time for building a common executable file in terminal is not working?

Tags: c

I am trying to build an executable file with two c code and i am linking these two with a header file "encrypt.h". But it is not working can you figure out why its not working?

This is my c file where I call encrypt function...it is named as message_hider.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "encrypt.h"


int main()
{   
  freopen("in.txt","r",stdin);
  char msg[80];
  while (fgets(msg, 80, stdin)) {
    encrypt(msg);
    printf("%s", msg);
  }
}
```

This is my header file encrypt.h

```
void encrypt(char *message);
```

This is encrypt.c file...

```
#include "encrypt.h"

void encrypt(char *message){
char c;
while(*message){
  *message=*message^31;
  *message++;
}
}
```

This is what getting when i am doing in the terminal but its not compiling...

```
gcc message_hider.c encrypt.c -o message_hider
/tmp/ccF56PqA.o: In function `main':
message_hider.c:(.text+0x3c): undefined reference to `encrypt'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Why is this?

Comment: The header file only *declares* that a function shall be available when linking. You need to compile, then link `encrypt.o` with your main program.

Comment: @Jongware: both source files are compiled & linked together. This should work, and does work (just tested). quidstone: What's that `page:message_hier.c` thing? are you sure you're compiling the right files?

Comment: @Mat I edited it...no Mat it doesn't work on my machine...I am getting this error

    "message_hider.c:(.text+0x3c): undefined reference to `encrypt'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status"

Comment: @quidstone: as I said, works for me. What compiler are you using? Did you check for typoes? Make sure you don't have old copies of the files, or files with confusingly similar names in your directory.

Comment: Can you place on gist.github.com (or similar) the output of `gcc -E message_hider.c encrypt.c`

Comment: @Mat I am using gcc on linux terminal. I think somewhere the linking is not done...no typoes i rechecked.

Comment: Compilation works for me too. (linux terminal with gcc 4.9.2)

Comment: @Bill heres the link. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3c1764d8a88a6f145a3c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `encrypt.c` you've misspelled the function name:

```
void encript(char *message){
```